# How to flatten very complex nested Json data

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested-lists

Below is the json input:

```
{'PatentBulkData': [{'patentCaseMetadata': {'applicationNumberText': {'value': '04558530',
     'electronicText': '04558530'},
    'filingDate': '1956-01-11',
    'applicationTypeCategory': 'Utility',
    'partyBag': {'applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag': [{'primaryExaminerOrAssistantExaminerOrAuthorizedOfficer': [{'name': {'personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName': [{'personFullName': 'SCHOFER, JOSEPH'}]}}]},
      {'partyIdentifierOrContact': [{'name': {'personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName': [{'personStructuredName': {'lastName': 'FRENCH, HUGHES & DOESCHER'}}]},
         'postalAddressBag': {'postalAddress': [{'postalStructuredAddress': {'addressLineText': [{'value': 'SUITE 1107'},
              {'value': '1825 K STREET, N. W.'}],
             'cityName': 'WASHINGTON',
             'geographicRegionName': [{'value': 'DC'}],
             'countryCode': 'US',
             'postalCode': '20006'}}]}}]}]},
    'groupArtUnitNumber': {'value': '1505', 'electronicText': '1505'},
    'applicationConfirmationNumber': '9850',
    'patentClassificationBag': {'cpcClassificationBagOrIPCClassificationOrECLAClassificationBag': [{'ipOfficeCode': 'US',
       'mainNationalClassification': {'nationalClass': '526',
        'nationalSubclass': '351000'}}]},
    'businessEntityStatusCategory': 'UNDISCOUNTED',
    'firstInventorToFileIndicator': 'Other',
    'inventionTitle': {'content': ['SOLID POLYMERS OF OLEFINS AND PRODUCTION OF SUCH POLYMERS']},
    'applicationStatusCategory': 'Patented Case',
    'applicationStatusDate': '1983-01-12',
    'officialFileLocationCategory': 'FILE REPOSITORY (FRANCONIA)',
    'officialFileLocationDate': '2019-12-09',
    'patentGrantIdentification': {'patentNumber': '4376851',
     'grantDate': '1983-03-15'}},
   'prosecutionHistoryDataBag': {'prosecutionHistoryData': [{'eventDate': '2001-09-21',
      'eventCode': 'SETS',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Set Application Status'},
     {'eventDate': '2000-03-01',
      'eventCode': 'FOND',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Case Found'},
     {'eventDate': '2000-03-01',
      'eventCode': 'LOST',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Case Reported Lost'},
     {'eventDate': '1987-02-20',
      'eventCode': 'TMOS',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Termination of Official Search'},
     {'eventDate': '1987-01-12',
      'eventCode': 'SRCH',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Official Search Conducted'},
     {'eventDate': '1986-12-19',
      'eventCode': 'TMOS',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Termination of Official Search'},
     {'eventDate': '1986-12-18',
      'eventCode': 'LOST',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Case Reported Lost'},
     {'eventDate': '1986-11-07',
      'eventCode': 'SRCH',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Official Search Conducted'},
     {'eventDate': '1986-11-04',
      'eventCode': 'LOST',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Case Reported Lost'},
     {'eventDate': '1986-06-20',
      'eventCode': 'LOST',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Case Reported Lost'},
     {'eventDate': '1986-05-01',
      'eventCode': 'TMOS',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Termination of Official Search'},
     {'eventDate': '1986-05-01',
      'eventCode': 'SRCH',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Official Search Conducted'},
     {'eventDate': '1986-04-23',
      'eventCode': 'LOST',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Case Reported Lost'},
     {'eventDate': '1985-10-01',
      'eventCode': 'SRCH',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Official Search Conducted'},
     {'eventDate': '1985-09-24',
      'eventCode': 'LOST',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Case Reported Lost'},
     {'eventDate': '1985-06-20',
      'eventCode': 'SRCH',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Official Search Conducted'},
     {'eventDate': '1985-06-20',
      'eventCode': 'LOST',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Case Reported Lost'},
     {'eventDate': '1982-11-24',
      'eventCode': 'N084',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Issue Fee Payment Verified'},
     {'eventDate': '1982-11-19',
      'eventCode': 'MN/=.',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Mail Notice of Allowance'},
     {'eventDate': '1982-11-19',
      'eventCode': 'N/=.',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Notice of Allowance Data Verification Completed'},
     {'eventDate': '1982-04-30',
      'eventCode': 'MCTNF',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Mail Non-Final Rejection'},
     {'eventDate': '1982-04-30',
      'eventCode': 'CTNF',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Non-Final Rejection'},
     {'eventDate': '1982-11-18',
      'eventCode': 'DOCK',
      'eventDescriptionText': 'Case Docketed to Examiner in GAU'}]},
   'assignmentDataBag': {'assignmentData': [{'reelNumber': '13158',
      'frameNumber': '318',
      'documentReceivedDate': '2002-08-09',
      'recordedDate': '2002-08-05',
      'mailDate': '2002-10-10',
      'pageTotalQuantity': 4,
      'conveyanceText': 'RELEASE OF SECURITY AGREEMENT',
      'assignorBag': {'assignor': [{'executionDate': '2002-04-30',
         'contactOrPublicationContact': [{'name': {'personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName': [{'value': 'BANKAMERICA BUSINESS CREDIT, INC., AS AGENT'}]}}]}]},
      'assigneeBag': {'assignee': [{'contactOrPublicationContact': [{'name': {'personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName': [{'value': 'HYUNDAI MOTOR AMERICA'}]},
           'postalAddressBag': {'postalAddress': [{'postalAddressText': [{'sequenceNumber': '1',
                'value': '10550 TALBERT AVENUE'},
               {'sequenceNumber': '2',
                'value': 'FOUNTAIN VALLEY CALIFORNIA 92708'}]}]}}]}]},
      'correspondenceAddress': {'partyIdentifierOrContact': [{'name': {'personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName': [{'value': 'JENKENS & GILCHRIST, P.C.'}]},
         'postalAddressBag': {'postalAddress': [{'postalAddressText': [{'sequenceNumber': '1',
              'value': 'ANDRE M. SZUWALSKI'},
             {'sequenceNumber': '2', 'value': '1445 ROSS AVENUE, STE. 3200'},
             {'sequenceNumber': '3', 'value': 'DALLAS, TX  75202-2799'}]}]}}]},
      'sequenceNumber': '1'}],
    'assignmentTotalQuantity': 1},
   'st96Version': 'V3_1',
   'ipoVersion': 'US_V8_0'}]}
```

first level with json_normalize, succeeded:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(jsonstr["PatentBulkData"], max_level = 0)
```

Below is the output:

[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3qOf.png)

But when I using the following code in order to go deeper, I get an error:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(jsonstr["PatentBulkData"], record_path = ["patentCaseMetadata"])
```

As you can see in this error:

```
raise TypeError(
    f"{js} has non list value {result} for path {spec}. "
    "Must be list or null."
```

screenshot attached:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4K6R.png)

My final goal is to normalize the entire file into a data frame.**

Comment: Hi, could you please try with a simpler json to see what exactly causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

Set your json to data and use flatten_json like so:

```
from flatten_json import flatten
dic_flattened = (flatten(d, '.') for d in data['PatentBulkData'])
df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)
```

Output

```
  patentCaseMetadata.applicationNumberText.value patentCaseMetadata.applicationNumberText.electronicText patentCaseMetadata.filingDate  ... assignmentDataBag.assignmentTotalQuantity st96Version ipoVersion
0                                       04558530                                           04558530                         1956-01-11  ...                                         1        V3_1    US_V8_0

[1 rows x 121 columns]
```

Check column names (you may want to change these)

```
df.columns

Index(['patentCaseMetadata.applicationNumberText.value',
       'patentCaseMetadata.applicationNumberText.electronicText',
       'patentCaseMetadata.filingDate',
       'patentCaseMetadata.applicationTypeCategory',
       'patentCaseMetadata.partyBag.applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag.0.primaryExaminerOrAssistantExaminerOrAuthorizedOfficer.0.name.personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName.0.personFullName',
       'patentCaseMetadata.partyBag.applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag.1.partyIdentifierOrContact.0.name.personNameOrOrganizationNameOrEntityName.0.personStructuredName.lastName',
       'patentCaseMetadata.partyBag.applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag.1.partyIdentifierOrContact.0.postalAddressBag.postalAddress.0.postalStructuredAddress.addressLineText.0.value',
       'patentCaseMetadata.partyBag.applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag.1.partyIdentifierOrContact.0.postalAddressBag.postalAddress.0.postalStructuredAddress.addressLineText.1.value',
       'patentCaseMetadata.partyBag.applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag.1.partyIdentifierOrContact.0.postalAddressBag.postalAddress.0.postalStructuredAddress.cityName',
       'patentCaseMetadata.partyBag.applicantBagOrInventorBagOrOwnerBag.1.partyIdentifierOrContact.0.postalAddressBag.postalAddress.0.postalStructuredAddress.geographicRegionName.0.value',
       ...
       'assignmentDataBag.assignmentData.0.correspondenceAddress.partyIdentifierOrContact.0.postalAddressBag.postalAddress.0.postalAddressText.0.sequenceNumber',
       'assignmentDataBag.assignmentData.0.correspondenceAddress.partyIdentifierOrContact.0.postalAddressBag.postalAddress.0.postalAddressText.0.value',
       'assignmentDataBag.assignmentData.0.correspondenceAddress.partyIdentifierOrContact.0.postalAddressBag.postalAddress.0.postalAddressText.1.sequenceNumber',
       'assignmentDataBag.assignmentData.0.correspondenceAddress.partyIdentifierOrContact.0.postalAddressBag.postalAddress.0.postalAddressText.1.value',
       'assignmentDataBag.assignmentData.0.correspondenceAddress.partyIdentifierOrContact.0.postalAddressBag.postalAddress.0.postalAddressText.2.sequenceNumber',
       'assignmentDataBag.assignmentData.0.correspondenceAddress.partyIdentifierOrContact.0.postalAddressBag.postalAddress.0.postalAddressText.2.value',
       'assignmentDataBag.assignmentData.0.sequenceNumber',
       'assignmentDataBag.assignmentTotalQuantity', 'st96Version',
       'ipoVersion'],
      dtype='object', length=121)
```